# Pop-up doesn't show

Tags: javascript, php, html

Can you tell me what's the problem with my code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function PopupCenter(pageURL, title,w,h) 
            {
                var left = (screen.width/2)-(w/2);
                var top = (screen.height/2)-(h/2);
                var targetWin = window.open (pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width='+w+', height='+h+', top='+top+', left='+left);
            } 
            </script>
            </head>


echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='PopupCenter('viewitem.php?Rid=".$row['refnumber']."','myPop1',1000,800)'>  View</a></td>";
```

Comment: Why do you ask us ? Do you get an error ? If so, what is it ?

Comment: Please provide your function PopupCenter code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to delete the one quote :

From this:

```
echo "<td><a href='#' onclick='PopupCenter('viewitem.php?Rid=".$row['refnumber']."','myPop1',1000,800)'>  View</a></td>";
```

To this:

```
echo "<td><a href='#' onclick=PopupCenter('viewitem.php?Rid=".$row['refnumber']."','myPop1',1000,800)>  View</a></td>";
```

Hope it works.